# Git integration with my Java EE application

Tags: git, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement where in I want to integrate GIT with my Java EE application. This application provides the user to work on an UI which would allow the user to modify content, add content by creating files and also perform visual diff with the previously committed version. Also, would provide the user to create branches, baselines etc.

Can you please point me to the right reference or provide me some insight ? I see there is something called JGit but that is more of an eclipse plugin. I want to do something very similart to http://www.scm-manager.org/screenshots/ but wonder, would I have to write everything from scratch or I can integrate SCM-Manager and change skins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've hit upon the best answer already - SCM-Manager.  I don't know that you'll be able to find an example that's closer.

If you look at the source it uses jGit under the covers.  jGit isn't an eclipse plugin, it's a java implementation of git, that happens to be used by eGit, which *is* an eclipse plugin.

If you do end up using SCM-Manager's source code, make sure you comply with its licencing!

Comment: Thanks Roy for the reply and clarification. So, I suppose if SCM-Manager licensing becomes an issue, I may have to refer to JGit source and build something like SCM-Manager grounds up. I understand that using JGit I can issue most of the commands, however, for the diff & merge operation, building an UI might be the only complex element.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that you'll find anything out of the box for that (but I could be wrong!)  Take a look at Gerrit, which is also open source and does provide git diffing using jGit as the git library