# GIT support for ACE online IDE

Tags: git, ide, egit, jgit, ace-editor

I have extended ACE - Code Editor for Web to support a language which we are developing. Now I want to add Git support or use GitHub APIs to the IDE which we built with ACE. I have looked into JGIT but I wonder if it will be possible to integrate it with ACE or not. I need to support some simple GIT feature like exploring the repo, push, pull, merge etc.

I want to do something like SCM Manger with my IDE.

I found a similar topic: [Git integration with my Java EE application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689159/git-integration-with-my-java-ee-application)

But it was not of much help.

Can someone point to the right direction to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ace is just an editor, it would require some plugin/backend logic to achieve this integration.

Ace just [decorates](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace#embedding-ace) your `div` (or `textarea`). It has limited control on what you do with the content.

If you want to integrate with Github or Bitbucket or any other provider, you would need to put in something in between that wires up the Ace frontend with git.

I have seen applications use the following -

1. [Gerrit](https://github.com/blog/270-the-fork-queue)
2. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/)

In both the above cases, ace editor was used as a frontend for code editing. Although, Gist in itself has a cool editor.

Edit - 
Yes, integrating with Github would make sense. You've probably have had a look at [Github Repositories API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/).
Also, have a look at [BitBucket API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs), if you are looking at alternatives.

There are a few Github client libraries available that can possibly make your life easier -

1. [C#](https://github.com/sgrassie/csharp-github-api)
2. [Java](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api)
3. [PHP](https://github.com/ornicar/php-github-api)

The documentation of these libraries would be worth skimming through, even if you decide to build your own :).

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975848/getting-private-repos-from-organization-with-github-api-v3) if you are planning to use Private Github repositories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really helpful. Gerrit looks a bit of a overkill for now and Gist does not have source code open :( I thinking to change my direction and look into Github APIs so that users can have their code on Github and not on our servers. For now my requirements are user authentication via github, browse repo, push, pull, commit and merge. Please share some pointers in this direction if you have any.